# R - Como remover todos os pacotes instalados?

Tags: r, packages

Rodei um script no R à um tempo atrás e acabei instalando todos os pacotes relacionados a estatística.

Com isso, sempre que vou fazer uma atualização, acaba demorando mais do que o preciso.

Como não uso nem metade desses pacotes, gostaria de saber se existe uma forma de remover todos os pacotes instalados (exceto os que são do sistema) de uma vez.

Não se isso importa, mas uso Linux Mint 19.3.

Comment: Esta pergunta pode ser respondida tal como está. E não é o mais trivial dos problemas, é potencialmente perigoso automatizar a remoção de uma quantidade indeterminada de pacotes.

Comment: Respondendo: ```update.packages(checkBuilt = T, ask = F)``` , ou, ```remove.packages( installed.packages( priority = "NA" )[,1] )```, ou, apagando a pasta do caminho ```/home/yourusername/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library```

Comment: Essa forma não parece ser a melhor. 1) O `update.packages` também vai demorar muito tempo. 3) Nem sempre esse é o diretório onde estão os pacotes, na minha instalação do R neste computador, por exemplo, estão em *dois* `caminho/para/site-library` diferentes.